# What's the opposite of the localtime function in Perl?

Tags: perl, timestamp

In Perl, `localtime` takes a Unix timestamp and gives back year/month/day/hour/min/sec etc.  I'm looking for the opposite of `localtime`: I have the parts, and I'd like to build a unix timestamp from them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[POSIX::mktime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#mktime)

Answer (score 17):

You can use the timelocal function in the [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Local) CPAN module.

> NAME
>
> Time::Local - efficiently compute time
>   from local and GMT time
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> $time = timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year);
> $time = timegm($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This module provides functions that
>   are the inverse of built-in perl
>   functions localtime() and gmtime().
>   They accept a date as a six-element
>   array, and return the corresponding
>   time(2) value in seconds since the
>   system epoch (Midnight, January 1,
>   1970 GMT on Unix, for example). This
>   value can be positive or negative,
>   though POSIX only requires support for
>   positive values, so dates before the
>   system's epoch may not work on all
>   operating systems.
>
> It is worth drawing particular
>   attention to the expected ranges for
>   the values provided. The value for the
>   day of the month is the actual day (ie
>   1..31), while the month is the number of months since January (0..11). This
>   is consistent with the values returned
>   from localtime() and gmtime().

**Note:** [POSIX::mktime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#mktime) is a just a wrapper around your C library's `mktime()` function.  Time::Local is a pure-Perl implementation, and always returns results matching Perl's `localtime`.  Also, Time::Local offers `gmtime`, while `mktime` only works in local time.  (Well, you could try changing `$ENV{TZ}`, but that doesn't work on some systems.)

Comment: I'm don't know what differences, if any, exist between Time::Local and POSIX::mktime, but I've always used Time::Local and never had any problems with it.

Comment: Note: Perl's localtime is just a wrapper around your C library's localtime or localtime_r function, and always returns results matching C's mktime.  :)

Comment: Well, there's a patch that makes Perl's localtime y2038 safe, even if your C library's version isn't. I don't think it's been integrated by default yet, but it likely will be. It fixes Time::Local, but I don't think it patches POSIX::mktime.

Answer (score 7):

[DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) on CPAN might of of some use. It also has a **lot** of time manipulation/translation methods.

Just create the DateTime using your parts and call $datetime->formatter("%s") ;

Comment: Yes. When in doubt, use DateTime -- the One True Perl time system. Jumping back and forth between crufty date/time tools is hellacious.